# Line between results autocomplete

Tags: android, autocomplete

I created a custom autocomplete from database and I noticed the results (drop down list) aren't separated by a line.
Is there a way to create this line?

Thank you!

Example:

result A

---

result B

Comment: Just some line to seperate results, Edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a generic View between the two TextViews.
Give this View a **1dp** height and a background color (or a drawable) to your wish.
Also make the View's width be `match_parent`.

So:

```
<TextView
    ...
/>
<!-- Separator -->
<View
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:width="1dp"
    android:background="#f000"
/>
<TextView
    ...
/>
```

Replace the TextViews with your actual TextViews

Comment: Thank you, I understood the genral idea